# changing url pattern using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, url

I guess I am a total noobie on PHP.

I am trying to change a url pattern to another pattern

from

http://da.feedsportal.com/c/34762/f/640634/s/2dd0817c/l/0L0Sexample0Bco0Bkr0Carti0Cpolitics0Cassembly0C5933970Bhtml/ia1.htm

to

http://www.example.co.kr/arti/politics/assembly/593397.html

so I am only taking "example0Bco0Bkr0Carti0Cpolitics0Cassembly0C5933970Bhtml" from the original url and tweak a bit '0B' -> '.' and '0C' -> '/'

Other parts like da.feedsportal.com/c/34762/f/640634/s/2dd0817c/l/0L0S and /ia1.htm shall be removed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The question is what is the pattern to the URLs?

Comment: @SH That's right. I will replace it with 'code'(preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$urls);)

Comment: @SH $pattern should be a pattern of original url while $replacement should be a patter of url intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **strpos** , **strrpos**, **substr** and **str_replace**. Were gonna take it in 4 main steps. Find start and end of substring. A touch of validation. Grab the substring. Convert substring.

Basicly:

```
function convert ($inputString) {
    $start = strpos( $inputString, '0L0S' );
    $end = strrpos( $inputString, '/' );

    if(! $start){
        return false;
    }

    $start = $start + 4; // this is because strpos gives start of found string
    $length = $end - $start;
    $innerString = substr( $inputString, $start, $length);

    $pass1 = str_replace ('0B', '.', $innerString);
    $pass2 = str_replace ('0C', '/', $pass1);

    return $pass2;
}
```

I'm sure there is a fancy way of doing this. But this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
echo urlencode("http://www.example.co.kr/arti/politics/assembly/593397.html");
//=> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.co.kr%2Farti%2Fpolitics%2Fassembly%2F593397.html
```

Then you don't have to write it on your own

Comment: Well....I need to get a pattern and change it with preg_replace. See comment on the question please and help me. :)

Comment: I am helping you. Whatever you're doing in your code above is just... wrong. If you encode the url data properly, you won't have to implement your own crazy brittle regexp solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746230/php-preg-match-url-replacement-usage Here is the history of my question. :) I am replacing one pattern to other since the url pattern I am getting from the feed does not really link a user to a right place. :)